# Calling functions with the same name in a list of namespaces

Tags: c++

I have several namespaces, each with the same set of function names:

```cpp
namespace one {
void a();
void b();
void c();
}

namespace two {
void a();
void b();
void c();
}

namespace three {
void a();
void b();
void c();
}
```

Is there a nice way I can refactor the following code to avoid duplication?

```cpp
one::a();
two::a();
three::a();

one::b();
two::b();
three::b();

while(true) {
  one::c();
  two::c();
  three::c();
}
```

For example, in pseudocode, is there a way I can express

```cpp
for (name: {one, two, three}) {
  name::a();
}
```

cleanly?

I am also able to rewrite/restructure the function definitions, if there is a more idiomatic way to express the same idea.

Comment: Your pseudo way is not supported in C++ as namespaces are not types. But I would like to see what others have to say.

Comment: Preprocessor magic to the rescue. :)

Comment: You could use a class with static functions instead of a namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have a full freedom on choosing mechanisms to use and c++14 compatible compiler I'd probably use tag dispatching + argument dependent lookup flavored with generic lambda to customize function call (choose the function to call afterwards):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace one {
struct Tag { } tag;
void a(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void b(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void c(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
}

namespace two {
struct Tag { } tag;
void a(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void b(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void c(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
}

namespace three {
struct Tag { } tag;
void a(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void b(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
void c(Tag) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
}

template <class L, class... Ts>
void foreach(L&& l, Ts&& ...ts) {
    int execute[] = { 0, (l(ts), 1)... };
    static_cast<void>(execute);
}

int main() {
    foreach([](auto tag) { a(tag); }, one::tag, two::tag, three::tag);
}
```

output:

> ```
> void one::a(one::Tag)
> void two::a(two::Tag)
> void three::a(three::Tag)
> ```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dLbFSEKub8WlLiu3)

Answer (score 11):

You can't iterate through namespaces like that, but you could iterate through the different functions by explicitly listing them:

```cpp
for (auto f : {one::a, two::a, three::a})
{
    f();
}
```

If you need to do this a lot though, I'd probably just write a function in global scope to call all the others. Or you could write a macro to shorthand the list above:

```cpp
#define func_list(name) {one::name, two::name, three::name}

for (auto f : func_list(a))
{
    f();
}
```

It sort of depends on what you need to do in specific cases. However I would just suggest renaming them to be different or making differently-named wrapper functions in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn your namespaces into types.

```
struct one {
  static void a();
  static void b();
  static void c();
};

struct two {
  static void a();
  static void b();
  static void c();
};

struct three {
  static void a();
  static void b();
  static void c();
};
```

Then to call all the `a` functions, then all the `b` functions, then all the `c` functions:

```
template <typename... Namespaces>
void foo() {
  (Namespaces::a(), ...); // expands into one::a(), two::a(), three::a()
  (Namespaces::b(), ...);
  (Namespaces::c(), ...);
}

foo<one, two, three>();
```